# How to write optimised SELECT SQL query or Java batch

Tags: java, sql, select, db2

I have an orders table as shown below.

```
    +----------+-------------+---------+--------------+
    | Name     | orderDate   | memberId| OrderId      |
    +----------+-------------+---------+--------------+
    |      Tom |  01-01-2023 |     ABC | 111          |
    |     Dick |  01-01-2023 |     XYZ | 222          |
    |    Harry |  01-01-2023 |     PQR | 666          |
    |     Dick |  01-01-2023 |     XYZ | 222          |
    |      Tom |  02-01-2023 |     ABC | 111          |
    |    Harry |  03-01-2023 |     PQR | 666          |
    |     Dick |  03-01-2023 |     XYZ | 222          |
    |      Tom |  04-01-2023 |     ABC | 111          |
    |     Dick |  06-01-2023 |     XYZ | 222          |
    |     Dick |  07-01-2023 |     XYZ | 222          |
    |    Harry |  04-01-2023 |     PQR | 666          |
    |     Dick |  08-01-2023 |     XYZ | 222          |
    |      Tom |  05-01-2023 |     ABC | 111          |
    |    Harry |  05-01-2023 |     PQR | 666          |
    |    Harry |  06-01-2023 |     PQR | 666          |
    |    Harry |  07-01-2023 |     PQR | 666          |
    +----------+-------------+---------+--------------+
```

**Expected Result:**
I have a list of memberIds -> ABC, XYZ, PQR (This list can be any size approx 200 max)
I need to select the latest 3 orders for each member.

```
    +----------+-------------+---------+--------------+
    | Name     | orderDate   | memberId| OrderId      |
    +----------+-------------+---------+--------------+
    |      Tom |  01-01-2023 |     ABC | 111          |
    |      Tom |  02-01-2023 |     ABC | 111          |
    |      Tom |  04-01-2023 |     ABC | 111          |
    |     Dick |  02-01-2023 |     XYZ | 111          |
    |     Dick |  01-01-2023 |     XYZ | 111          |
    |     Dick |  03-01-2023 |     XYZ | 111          |
    |    Harry |  01-01-2023 |     PQR | 111          |
    |    Harry |  03-01-2023 |     PQR | 111          |
    |    Harry |  04-01-2023 |     PQR | 111          |
    +----------+-------------+---------+--------------+
```

How can I write an optimized select query for the above scenario?

Currently, I created a DB2 hibernate SQL query dynamically in for loop.
The problem with this approach is that my query length grows too big for DB2 and returns an error as I have 200 memberId

> -101  The statement is too long or too complex

```
(SELECT * FROM orders WHERE memberId='ABC' ORDERBY orderDate DESC FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM orders WHERE memberId='XYZ' ORDERBY orderDate DESC FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM orders WHERE memberId='PQR' ORDERBY orderDate DESC FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY)
```

Probable Solutions:

1. Divide memberIds list into smaller batches, call select multiple times, and aggregate results in my java code.
2. Any other way to fetch this result from SQL?

Please share your opinion from a query or java point of view.
Thank you

Comment: This can be done easily with the `row_number` function. You need 3 latest orders for each member, but showed the result with the 3 earliest ones. So, what do you really need exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE to store your long member list.

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.MEMBERS (MEMBERID CHAR(3)) 
WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED;

INSERT INTO SESSION.MEMBERS VALUES 'ABC';
...
INSERT INTO SESSION.MEMBERS VALUES 'XYZ';

WITH MYTAB (Name, orderDate, memberId, OrderId) AS
(
VALUES
  ('  Tom', date ('01.01.2023'), 'ABC', 111)
, (' Dick', date ('01.01.2023'), 'XYZ', 222)
, ('Harry', date ('01.01.2023'), 'PQR', 666)
, (' Dick', date ('01.01.2023'), 'XYZ', 222)
, ('  Tom', date ('02.01.2023'), 'ABC', 111)
, ('Harry', date ('03.01.2023'), 'PQR', 666)
, (' Dick', date ('03.01.2023'), 'XYZ', 222)
, ('  Tom', date ('04.01.2023'), 'ABC', 111)
, (' Dick', date ('06.01.2023'), 'XYZ', 222)
, (' Dick', date ('07.01.2023'), 'XYZ', 222)
, ('Harry', date ('04.01.2023'), 'PQR', 666)
, (' Dick', date ('08.01.2023'), 'XYZ', 222)
, ('  Tom', date ('05.01.2023'), 'ABC', 111)
, ('Harry', date ('05.01.2023'), 'PQR', 666)
, ('Harry', date ('06.01.2023'), 'PQR', 666)
, ('Harry', date ('07.01.2023'), 'PQR', 666)
)
SELECT Name, orderDate, memberId, OrderID
FROM
(
SELECT 
    T.*
  , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY orderDate DESC) AS RN_
FROM MYTAB T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SESSION.MEMBERS M WHERE M.MEMBERID = T.MEMBERID)
) T
WHERE RN_ <= 3
ORDER BY Name, orderDate DESC;
```

| NAME | ORDERDATE | MEMBERID | ORDERID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 2023-01-05 | ABC | 111 |
| Tom | 2023-01-04 | ABC | 111 |
| Tom | 2023-01-02 | ABC | 111 |
| Dick | 2023-01-08 | XYZ | 222 |
| Dick | 2023-01-07 | XYZ | 222 |
| Dick | 2023-01-06 | XYZ | 222 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qFYrjAyd)

Comment: You beat me to it:⁠-⁠) Just like to add that it can be beneficial to create an index on the temporary table

Comment: The index is not needed, since it will never be used probably. The expected plan is `NLJOIN (TBSCAN (MEMBERS), IXSCAN (MYTAB))`. It's hard to imagine a plan when `MEMBER` is on the inner leg of some `xJOIN`. It could be in case of vast majority members in this table, but it's `TBSCAN (MYTAB)` and probably `TBSCAN (MEMBERS)` as well...

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I was wondering do I need to fire like 200 inserts in temp table if I have 200 ids ?

Comment: Either 200 single row insert statements or just 1 such a statement with a batch of 200 rows. [Making batch updates in JDBC applications](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=sql-making-batch-updates-in-jdbc-applications)

Answer (score 0):

**row_number()** with **partition by** clause solves your use case.

Here is the query for the same

```
select rs.name, rs.order_date, rs.member_id, rs.order_id from (select *, row_number() over (partition by member_id order by order_date desc) as `order` from orders where member_id in ('XYZ', 'ABC')) as rs where rs.order <= 3;
```

Comment: member_id in ('XYZ', 'ABC')) problem is when I have 500 member_id. This SQL will be rejected by DB2

Comment: Is it working for 200 member_id's ? because the `expected result` in your ask has 200 member_id max